Interdependent numeric fields
I am using Datatables Editor and have 3 numeric fields which are interdependent:

when I input a numeric data in the first one, the value of the second one must adjust to be equal to the value of the third one (if present) less the value of the first one, multiplied by ten thousand --> 2 = (3-1)*10000
when I input a numeric data in the second one, the value of the third one must adjust to be equal to the value of the first one plus the value of the second one divided by ten thousand --> 3 = 1 +2/10000
when I input a numeric data in the third one, the value of the second one must adjust to be equal to the value of the third one less the value of the first one multiplied by ten thousand --> 2 = (3 -1)/10000

The 3rd part works fine with the following code:
    editor.dependent( 'tms_ft_financialtransaction.RateDeal', function ( val, data, callback ) {
        if (editor.field('tms_ft_financialtransaction.RateSpot').val() ) {
            editor.field('tms_ft_financialtransaction.RateMargin').val((parseFloat(editor.field('tms_ft_financialtransaction.RateDeal').val()) - parseFloat(editor.field('tms_ft_financialtransaction.RateSpot').val()) )*10000);
        }
        callback(true);
    } );

The problem that I have is that when I replicate the same code for the second part, when amending the second field, the third field is recalculated, which recalculates the second one, which recalculates the third one, which recalculates the second one, etc.
Does anybody know how I can fix that?
